# Probability Mass Function of the Time of First Return to $0$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, proof-writing, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Fix a number p with $0 < p < 1$. Consider the Markov chain on the non-negative integers $\{0, 1, 2, . . .\}$ whose transition probabilities are given by $P_{n,n+1} =p, P_{n,0} =1−p$, forall $n≥0$.
>
> > (a) Is this Markov chain irreducible? Explain.
> >
> > (b) Is the state 0 periodic or aperiodic? Explain.
> >
> > (c) Suppose that the Markov chain is initially in state $0$, and let $T_0$ denote the time of first return to $0$ (i.e., $T_0$ is the smallest value of $n > 0$ such that $X_n = 0$, if such a value exists, and otherwise $T_0 = ∞$). Determine the probability mass function of $T_0$.
> >
> > (d) What exactly does it mean to say that 0 is a recurrent state?
> >
> > (e) Prove that 0 a recurrent state.

This is a past final exam from my university. I don't have much confidence on discrete Markov Chains. Can you please verify my answer for part (a), (b), (c), and provide me with some enlightenment on part (d), (e)?

**My answer:**

(a) Yes, because all states communicate with each other.

(b) Aperiodic. Because it can come back to itself in one step therefore, having period of 1.

(c) $\pi_0 = \pi_0 p_{0,0} + \pi_1 p_{1,0} + \pi_2 p_{2,0} + \cdots $

$\pi_0 = (1-p)( \pi_0 + \pi_1  + \pi_2  + \cdots )$

$\pi_0 = (1-p)(\sum_{i \geq 0} \pi_i )$

$\therefore \pi_0 = (1-p), T_0 = \frac{1}{1-p}$

(d) I know by definition: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} p(X_n=0) = 1$

(e) Should I say that because $T_0$ is finite and therefore, it is recurrent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was inspired by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251202/prove-that-markov-chain-is-recurrent) to solve (e).

Let $\tau_{00} = \inf \{ n>0 : X_n = 0 | X_0=0 \}$. Then $\tau_{00} = 1$ with probability $1-p$  and  $\tau_{00} > 1$ with probability $p$. In the second case, $\tau_{00} = 1 + T$ where $T$  has the geometric distribution with success probability $1-p$.  Therefore, $E[\tau_{00}] = 1 + \frac{1}{1-p} < \infty$. Therefore, it is recurrent.